# 22.04 LTS hangs at text logon screen

Tags: boot

I used to see this login text flash by very tiny in the upper left corner during startup but now it is large and stays there. I tried entering my logon but it will not accept it and simply clears itself and goes back to the same prompt. I also tried root but it made no difference.

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS WebDev tty1

WebDev login:
```

Any ideas how to get around this to continue booting? This is a desktop system and I can boot to another device, then browse to the files and folders which all appear to be there but the boot does not find them. Maybe some kind of conflict but if so, I can’t find it. I just did a fresh install but it made no difference.

Comment: That looks like it's booted to me, ie. you've got a text login prompt, which is normal if you're asking about a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server system, or a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop system where the desktop packages are removed.  You didn't actually specify beyond the basic release details.

Comment: Sorry, this is a desktop system so just the text login was unexpected. The system is there as I can see the files and folders but the boot is apparently not seeing it.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?    Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format with 2000 being added to the year; your login says 2022-Februrary release, when none occurred in February. I likely missed that last time, but it maybe a sign of a corrupted or non-Ubuntu system. I'd explore your *apt* logs of your last session using terminal, as you possibly made a change that caused your system to switch from desktop to server, or removed/disabled desktop packages; and the best fix is always to revert whatever you did (*not try random suggestions online*). Please check your details.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo which I will correct. it is 22.04. Thank you for pointing it out. I always wondered where they came up with the version numbers!